# Analyse JasperReports export output

Tags: java, unit-testing, pdf, jasper-reports

again - Jasperreports...

So, we've got reports with charts and tables which look similar to this:

```
JAN | FEB | MAR | ... | DEC | SUM
----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
 5  |  1  |  9  | 120 | 20  | 155
(Numbers represent amounts of vehicles)
```

Beneath these tables there are multiple tables which consist of the data from the above table in a deeper detail (in a drill down manner).

We export these reports to PDF and serve them in a web application as downloadable documents. The needed data is calculated in specialized Java factories. Per report there is one factory which serves a list with dumb data objects. These objects contain the aggregated numbers which are displayed in the charts and tables.

Additionally the numbers are hyperlinks. They forward to a servlet which offers an XLS export which contains detailed data about each vehicle. Of course, each hyperlink has a bunch of parameters for the servlet.

**What we want to have:**

A full automated test which does the following:

- Check the data integrity of each table (is the number in the sum column really the sum of each column before)
- Check the data integrity of the detailed tables in respect to the superior table (sum of JAN columns = number in JAN column of the superior table)
- Get the hyperlink of each number and feed the XLS export with it to check if the number of vehicles in the XLS is equal to the displayed number in the table

So the test should work similar to this:

```
Test -> generate PDF report -> check table integrity -> parse links -> check XLS -> assertEverythingLooksFine()
```

**What we have tried:**

Currently the PDF report is written to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to forward the data to a `PdfReader` which parses it with a `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`. This way it's possible to check the table integrity although it's quite cumbersome. Additionally it is not possible to get the hyperlinks. Another idea is exporting the report to HTML instead of PDF to get the hyperlinks. Checking table integrity is even more cumbersome because JasperReports doesn't generate HTML tables but a bunch of DIVs.

**Additional notes:**

- Yes, table integrity could also be checked on the basis of the factory's output - the idea came to me while writing this question. But the really important point to test is the XLS export and the parameters for the export are generated in JasperReports

  - Yes, generating the export parameters could also be done in the factory but i don't think that it belongs there (tier architecture and so on)
- I know, analyzing binary-format output in a Unit-Test is a bad idea, but JasperReports is quite a black box and we do a lot of work in the jrxml-stuff
- I also thought of some sort of formatter/customizer which accesses the elements while generating
- I have read http://whathaveyoutried.com and tried my best ;)

**My questions:**

- What do you think of the approach? Is it reasonable?
- Is there some point I have missed which could be done better?
- Has JasperReports some sort of API or interface which could be accessed to access the generated output more easily? Maybe the formatter/customizer approach?
- Are there better APIs for reading PDF?
- Have i forgot reasonable questions? ;)

**Which versions we use:**

- Java 1.6
- POI 3.8
- iText 5.1.3
- JasperReports 4.7.1

I hope this question is not too messed up and you don't beat me to death verbally ;)

Comment: Hi, SO works in simple scheme, One question one answer. If you have so many topic the best way is to contact someone from JasperSoft. The are very helpfull persons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vash said, this is no place where a topic like this can be answered / discussed.

Nevertheless i will post our solution in case of someone having a similar problem and finding this site.

**Getting the needed - by JasperReports generated - output**

Neither generating HTML instead of PDF nor parsing the final PDF document with some kind of API is a really satisfying solution. What we did is writing a scriptlet which we linked to the report. In the report the scriplet is called where the number of vehicles is displayed. The number of vehicles and the generated link are passed to the scriplet as parameters and the method returns the number again.

Now the scriplet has a static `Map<String, Double>` which collects all links and numbers. After generating the report we can grab this `Map` and analyse the corresponding XLS export. This way we can compare the amounts of vehicles in PDF and XLS.

The drawback of this method is, that the PDF report is generated into an empty `OutputStream`.

**Checking the table data for integrity**

Fortunately the data which is displayed is generated in a java factory. So all we have to do is to instantiate it and check its output which is delivered in special data classes and collections. This way we can implicitly verify that the data in the report is correct.

Running a full unit test with a setup consisting of three reports and circa 240 XLS documents lasts about five minutes. As a byproduct we have a bunch full of XLS sheets (which are also written into empty `OutputStreams`) which is not very nice but on the other hand, it's only a unit test which doesn't have to be hyper efficient.